# Htaccess RewriteCond based on environment variable

Tags: htaccess, apache, mod-rewrite, custom-variables

I find apache very unfriendly.

Anyway. I have this:

```
RewriteRule (.*) - [QSA,E=DOMAIN_NAME:localhost.com]
```

This doesn't redirect, which is fine:

```
RewriteCond "www.%{ENV:DOMAIN_NAME}" "!=www.localhost.com"
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}?err=%{ENV:DOMAIN_NAME} [L,R=301]
```

This doesn't redirect, which is fine:

```
RewriteCond "%{HTTP_HOST}" "!=www.localhost.com"
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}?err=%{ENV:DOMAIN_NAME} [L,R=301]
```

This does redirect:

```
RewriteCond "www.%{ENV:DOMAIN_NAME}" "!=%{HTTP_HOST}"
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}?err=%{ENV:DOMAIN_NAME} [L,R=301]
```

Is very frustrating. I'm stuck in checking two variables if they match...

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: @davidgo I'm trying to check  if `www.%{ENV:DOMAIN_NAME}` contains the same value as `%{HTTP_HOST}`

Answer (score 2):

> This does redirect:
>
> ```
> RewriteCond "www.%{ENV:DOMAIN_NAME}" "!=%{HTTP_HOST}"
> ```

Because server variables of the form `%{VARNAME}` are not expanded in the *CondPattern* (2nd argument to the `RewriteCond` directive). You are comparing against the literal string "%{HTTP_HOST}", which is obviously different to "www.localhost.com", so the *condition* is successful.

You need to use a regex with an internal backreference instead. For example:

```
RewriteCond www.%{ENV:DOMAIN_NAME}@%{HTTP_HOST} !^([\w.]+)@\1$
```

Where `@` is just an arbitrary character that does not occur elsewhere in the string being checked. And `\1` is a backreference to the captured subpattern, ie. `([\w.]+)`.

Or use an Apache Expression (Apache 2.4):

```
RewriteCond expr "'local.%{ENV:DOMAIN_NAME}' != %{HTTP_HOST}"
```

*Aside:*

> ```
> RewriteRule (.*) - [QSA,E=DOMAIN_NAME:localhost.com]
> ```

If you are simply setting an env var then you don't need to capture (or even *match*) the entire URL-path and the `QSA` flag is superfluous (since there is no substitution). For example:

```
RewriteRule ^ - [E=DOMAIN_NAME:localhost.com]
```